# React what to use in production instead of proxy?

Tags: reactjs, apache, production

I know that the `proxy` setting in `package.json` only works in dev. So the question is:

How to make the application work in prod (after doing `yarn build)` and deploying into apache?

I've tried many things, nothing seems to work.

My REST API (server side) is a java running on `:8080`

When I deploy the app and try a request, the requests go to `localhost/api` instead of `localhost:8080/api`

My fetch all look like:

`` await fetch(`/api/group/${id}`, { ``.

What is the simplest and most flexible solution?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found so far and it works is to configure `VirtualHost` on the apache server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  ProxyPass /api/ http://localhost:8080/api/
  ProxyPassReverse /api/ http://localhost:8080/api/
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I had to enable modules and restart apache.

Steps (ubuntu):

1. `cd /etc/apache2/sites-available`
2. `sudo cp 000-default.conf react.conf`
3. `sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf`
4. `sudo a2ensite react.conf`
5. `sudo a2enmod` - here enabled `*` all
6. `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Now my `/api` points to `localhost:8080/api`